# How to modify incoming response headers using apache?

Tags: reactjs, apache, cors

I have a ReactJS application that I produced the production build for, and placed the build folder inside /var/www/html/ (I assume that is the correct way to deploy).

I am calling an API that does not support CORS from this ReactJS application. I found a lot of posts and questions about allowing CORS on apache, but I am not sure if that is what I am looking for. I followed these posts with no luck. I am suspecting these guides are for adding CORS to outgoing responses not incoming?

Anyway, what I added to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

I added these under `<Directory /var/www/html>`

I also tried adding the 4 lines above to .htaccess inside `/var/www/html/`

Again no success.

I want to mention that I have no way to modify the api server, and that I already succeeded in modifying the headers using a middle python flask application. However, I need to eliminate that python app and use Apache for this task.

Is it possible to use apache to modify incoming responses to the server where apache is deployed so that cors is enabled? If yes, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached a solution by following [this guide](https://chriscarey.com/blog/2014/06/13/apache-proxy-with-cors-headers/). Apparently, apache cannot intercept incoming responses and add headers to them. This is as far as my knowledge of course. What it can do, is act as a reverse proxy.

A reverse proxy works like this, my app should send the HTTP request to a url defined in apache "/api" for example. And inside the apache configuration, you define the "/api" location to redirect the request to whatever server url you need. Then you add the header using apache, which upon receiving the response from that server, adds the header and returns the response to you, with cors enable header. The code I used in apache is as follows:

```
<LocationMatch "/api">
   ProxyPass http://remote-server.com:8000/api/
   Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
</LocationMatch>
```